# Javascript DatePicker format year in 2 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using datepicker.
The problem I'm having is that the year is giving me 4 digits.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

Shouldn't yy give me only 2 digits?

How do I get 2 digits on the year instead of 4?

Comment: can u provide plunker or jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about JQuery.
Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
y - year (two digit)
yy - year (four digit)
```

So:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-y'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single `y`

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-y'
});
```

Source: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/