# dateformat not applying to datepicker jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({

            dateFormat: 'd-m-yyyy',
    onSelect: function (date) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'timesquery.php',
            data: {
                'date': date,
            },
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('select[name=times]').html(data);
        }).fail(function () {
            alert('An error has occured.')
        });
    }
        });
```

I have this jQuery code which uses datepicker, i set date format to "d-m-yyyy" but it is returning "dd-mm-yyyy"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript DatePicker format year in 2 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034419/javascript-datepicker-format-year-in-2-digits)

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong format, I need date and month with no leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

I used format instead of dateFormat and it worked.